# How do I add a line to check for negative numbers?

Tags: python, numbers

I am doing the course 'Automate the boring stuff with Python' and there is one stage where you have a try and except code. The author states you need to find a way to add a line of code that will print out a message if the user inputs a negative number. Nowhere do I find any explanation of how to do that.
Can anyone help?

I am using Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10.

```py
print('How many cats do I have?')
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats!')
    else:
        print('That is not that many cats.')
except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
```

Comment: From the code you already have, you know how to convert from the string input to an integer and check if that integer is at least 4. How would you modify that `if` statement to check whether the number of cats is non-negative?

Comment: Think about what a negative number is relative `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
print('How many cats do I have?')
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats!')
    elif int(numCats)<0:
        print ('n3gative no.')
    else:
        print('That is not that many cats.')
except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the try block, after if condition... Do this

```
elif int(numCats) < 0:
    print('negative number')
```

Comment: Your brackets are incorrect it's gotta be `int(numCats) <0`

Answer (score 0):

```
print('How many cats do I have?')
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats!')
    elif int(numCats) < 0:
        print("Input is less than zero!")
    else:
        print('That is not that many cats.')
except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
```

Use another if-statement.

If you want to throw back an error when a negative number is inserted and trigger your code in the exception block that way, you could use `raise`.

Like this:

```
#...

elif int(numCats) < 0:
    customError = ValueError("Only positive values allowed.")
    raise customError

#...
```

Comment: You gotta use elif here.. or else even when numCats is say 4 it'll print both if(1st if) and else part...it's because else here gets mapped to second if

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.